# QGraphicsView: Paint Rectangular Gradient

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to paint a rectangular gradient as the background for a QGraphicsView.

This image is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Notice the light gradient around the borders.

I tried using 4 QLinearGradients going from each border of the window to the opposite(From right to left, from top to bottom and so on). I don't think this approach is very efficient(painting so many gradient objects). Maybe a single QLinearGradient with the Spread set to ReflectSpread is enough, but I have a positioning issue. The idea is that the gradient should be like a visor, like the frame of a camera. It should always look the same regardless of QGraphicsView size or scale.

This is the code for the QLinearGradient:

```
    QLinearGradient lGrad;
    lGrad.setSpread(QGradient::ReflectSpread);
    lGrad.setStart(0, 500);
    lGrad.setColorAt(0, Qt::red);
    lGrad.setColorAt(1, Qt::blue);

    painter->fillRect(rect, lGrad);
```

I tried using a stylesheet around the border but it doesn't give me the desired results. It seems that gradients cannot be applied to borders, only to tooltips. Minimal example:

```
#include <QGraphicsView>

// View
class View : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
     explicit View(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
     {
         // Stylesheet
         setStyleSheet(
             "border-left:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
             "border-right:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
             "border-top:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
             "border-bottom:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
             "border-radius: 0.5px;"
             "padding: 1px;"
             "margin: 0px;"
             "spacing: 0px;"
             );

        // Hidden because the stylesheet adds colors to them
         setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
         setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

         setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
         setBackgroundBrush(QColor(35, 41, 56));
         setCacheMode(CacheBackground);
         setViewportUpdateMode(BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
         setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
         setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
         scale(qreal(0.8), qreal(0.8));
         setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
     }

     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
     {
         QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
         if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
         {
             _clickPos = mapToScene(event->pos());
         }
     }

     void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
     {
         QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
         if (scene()->mouseGrabberItem() == nullptr && event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
         {
             if ((event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) == 0)
             {
                 QPointF difference = _clickPos - mapToScene(event->pos());
                 setSceneRect(sceneRect().translated(difference.x(), difference.y()));
             }
         }
     }
}
// Main
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;

    auto view = new View;
    view->setScene(scene);

    auto window = new QMainWindow;
    window->setCentralWidget(view);
    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what the final output you are considering should look like. could you add one picture with photoshop or something like this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Parisa.H.R. Something like this: https://i.gyazo.com/fd5ed3c55b17f8834e95e42f6d8079fe.png
I want it to have an absolute position, so I  change the window size, move the "camera" or zoom in and out the gradient should always be surrounding the view.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: 4 gradients approach is perfectly fine

Comment: @mugiseyebrows What can I do to have the gradient in an absolute positioning? Looking like a "visor" as I mentioned above.

Comment: Ok here is a better example: https://i.gyazo.com/e51312fc5505e0860f58704391c81f82.gif
I added a radial gradient to the center of the view, and obviously it stays at the center when I move the camera. I want it to move with the camera, always at the center. Is that possible?

Comment: @Tac, Please try my answer, just copy and past that Stylesheet in your graphicsView or set it, I tested it by changing the window size, moving the "camera" or zooming in and out and it works well.it always is surrounding the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, two in fact. The idea is to paint the gradient at the borders of the QGraphicsView. The effect should be constant and not affected by panning the view or resizing the widget. Results:
https://i.gyazo.com/af979432e86b9ecf3848a0114d950531.gif

1. Draw the gradient in **QGraphicsView::drawBackground()** using the QGraphicsView's rectangle but making sure that the background is not cached. Make sure **setCacheMode(CacheBackground);** is not set. If this is set, there will be artifacts.

   ```
   QLinearGradient leftGrad;
   leftGrad.setStart(rect.left(), 0);
   leftGrad.setFinalStop(rect.left() + 200, 0);
   leftGrad.setColorAt(0.0, gradientColor);
   leftGrad.setColorAt(gradientPosition, Qt::transparent);
   painter->fillRect(rect, leftGrad);
   ```
2. Draw the gradient in **QGraphicsView::drawForeground()** instead. This allows to keep the background cached for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create it by using **Stylesheet** and this is my result:

[image]

I add one `graphicsView` Widget in my `centralwidget` and add this **Stylesheet**:

```
border-left:20px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(32, 180, 214,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );

border-right:20px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(32, 180, 214,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );

border-top:20px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(32, 180, 214,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );

border-bottom:20px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(32, 180, 214,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );

border-radius: 0.5px;
padding: 1px;
margin: 0px;
spacing: 0px;
```

I tried to get your color, but if you play with its RGB, you can get the color you want.
I think this is the cleanest solution possible because by changing the size of the view, everything changes the same and the Style remains constant.

[image]

**Edited and Updated:**
you shouldn't add `setBackgroundBrush(QColor(35, 41, 56));` to your `QGraphicsView` and `View` class . I remove this line and instead I add this in MainWindow as setStyleSheet. like this :

**in View class :**

```
View::View()
{
    // Stylesheet
    setStyleSheet(
        "border-left:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
        "border-right:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
        "border-top:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
        "border-bottom:40px solid qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:0, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0,150), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) );"
        "border-radius: 0.5px;"
        "padding: 1px;"
        "margin: 0px;"
        "spacing: 0px;"
        );

// Hidden because the stylesheet adds colors to them
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
// setBackgroundBrush(QColor(35, 41, 56));
    setCacheMode(CacheBackground);
    setViewportUpdateMode(BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
    setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
    scale(qreal(0.8), qreal(0.8));
    setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
}
```

**and in MainWindow class:**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 41, 43);");

    auto  scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    auto  view  = new View;
    view->setScene(scene);
    setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

**This is The Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted but I can't use it. If I set the gradient from a color to transparency it will turn the transparency into black. According to the documentation transparency is not supported in this case: https://i.gyazo.com/4513a2825143ccffdb4d2ff4547c0146.png

This is how it looks:
https://i.gyazo.com/11b37830e418cfeacc087ba38ffdf9bc.gif

Comment: @Tac Well this is another issue, if you can create one GitHub repo and add me, I should see what is your code. I didn't understand why you attach a picture about QTooltip.I add this border to my  graphicsView object.

Comment: thanks. I edited my question to add a minimal example.

Comment: @Tac please try it you should add a base background color to MainWindow not  View

Comment: Thanks for trying @Parisa.H.R. The problem is that I need the background. I'm overriding the drawBackground method to draw a grid on the view. Sorry for not including that. I was trying to simplify it as much as possible. This is how it looks:
https://i.gyazo.com/b7f615c7f7ff6469129bc130cad403ab.gif
Stylesheets also pass down the effect to the children which I don't want. 

I'm trying to draw the gradient directly in the background of the view gut I can't get it right there either.